# Can catch() be written to convert from one object type to another?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

Given this code, where `A` is in a 3rd-party library, and `B` is code I wrote:

```
class A {...};
class B { public: B( const A &a ); ... };

try
{
    A a(...);
    throw a;
}
catch ( const B &b )
{
    // ...do stuff with B, like log the details to a file...
}
```

If an object `A` is thrown, then my `catch B` is skipped.  I was hoping since `B` has a constructor that takes an `A` object, that this might work.

Is there something I can do to make this work, or do I have to modify all `catch` clauses to handle catching both `A` and `B`?

Comment: Could you make B a derived class of A, and then `catch (const A&) {...}` everywhere instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that cannot work. User-defined conversions are not taken into consideration when matching a thrown object to a handler. Per paragraph 15.3/3 of the C++11 Standard:

> A handler is a match for an exception object of type `E` if
>
> - The handler is of type `cv T` or `cv T&` and `E` and `T` are the same type (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers),
>     or
> - the handler is of type `cv T` or `cv T&` and `T` is an unambiguous public base class of `E`, or
> - the handler is of type `cv T` or `const T&` where `T` is a pointer type and `E` is a pointer type that can be
>     converted to `T` by either or both of
>
>   - a standard pointer conversion (4.10) not involving conversions to pointers to private or protected
>       or ambiguous classes
>   - a qualification conversion
> - the handler is of type `cv T` or `const T&` where `T` is a pointer or pointer to member type and `E` is
>     `std::nullptr_t`.